# wget to call a php script but it creates output

Tags: php, wget, cron

I am calling **wget** from **crontab** to periodically call a php script on my site:

```
wget -q http://mydomain.com/myscript?pa=doscript >/dev/null 2>&1
```

It works fine, but in the root dir of my webspace each call **creates output files** called

```
myscript?pa=doscript
myscript?pa=doscript.1 ...
```

I tried to supress the output with -q and >/dev/null 2>&1 but obviously it does not work. **Why?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
wget -O /dev/null -q http://mydomain.com/myscript?pa=doscript >/dev/null 2>&1
```

This tells `wget` to save the file to `/dev/null` essentially discarding it.

See `man wget` and the `-O` option.

Answer (score 1):

Just call PHP from the cron job instead of wget:

```
php -f /path/to/myscript pa=doscript
```

Or:

```
/usr/bin/php -f /path/to/myscript pa=doscript
```

This assumes the [small trick](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php#108883) to import `$_GET` variables from the command line:

```
parse_str(implode('&', array_slice($argv, 1)), $_GET);
```

Or, you can rewrite your script to use [`$argc`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argc.php) and [`$argv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php).

Comment: question: could he have used curl instead? would it matter?

Comment: Probably, but you're invoking a web server that's local to the same server - It's inefficient and just plain not worth it. Much easier and more efficient to just call PHP directly.